# Using the definition of convexity to show what a line in $\mathbb R^k$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I'm doing this exercise to test my understanding.

I'm represented with a line in $\mathbb R^k$ in a parameterised form (set, I'm not sure what the proper English word is)

$$\mathcal{L} = \left\{
a+tb | t \in \mathbb R
  \right\}$$

**My method** 
Let $x$ and $y$ to arbitrary points on the line $\mathcal L$, then there must exist $t_1,t_2 \in \mathbb R$ such that

$$ x = a+ t_1b \quad \text{and} \quad y = a+ t_2b$$

Applying the formal definition I have

$$\(\begin{aligned} \lambda x+(1-\lambda) y &=\lambda(a+t_1 b)+(1-\lambda)\left(a+t_{2} b\right) \\ &=\lambda a+\lambda t_1b+a+t_{2} b-\lambda a-\lambda t_{2} b \\ &=a+\lambda t_{1} b+t_{2} b-\lambda t_{2} b \\ &=a+\left(\lambda t_{1}+t_{2}-\lambda t_{2}\right) b \\ &=a+\left(\lambda t_{1}+(1-\lambda) t_{2}\right) b \end{aligned}\)$$

Conclusion: since $a+\left(\lambda t_{1}+(1-\lambda) t_{2}\right) b$ has the form as the parameterisation of the line, the line is convex.

I'm not sure how to phrase the conclusion in words.

Another question is: if I'm going to show that a hyperplane also is convex, in which form should I write the hyperplane in and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say that the segment between any two points on the line is included within said line.

If $H \subseteq \Bbb R^k$ is a $d$-dimensional hyperplane, then you may parametrize it by
$$ \mathbf a + t_1 \mathbf b_1 + \dots + t_d\mathbf b_d,$$
where $\mathbf a \in H$ and $\{\mathbf b_i\}$ is a basis of the vector subspace $H - \mathbf a$. From here you should be able to show that the segment between two arbitrary $\mathbf x’, \mathbf x’’\in H$ is contained in $H$ through a sequence of steps similar to those you posted in your answer.